# React hooks - How to call useEffect on demand?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am rewriting a CRUD table with React hooks. The custom hook `useDataApi` below is for fetching data of the table, watching the url change - so it'll be triggered when params change. But I also need to fetch the freshest data after delete and edit. How can I do that?

```
const useDataApi = (initialUrl, initialData) => {
  const [url, setUrl] = useState(initialUrl)

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(dataFetchReducer, { data: initialData, loading: true })

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_INIT' })
      const result = await instance.get(url)
      dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_SUCCESS', payload: result.data })
    }

    fetchData()
  }, [url])

  const doFetch = url => {
    setUrl(url)
  }

  return { ...state, doFetch }
}
```

Since the `url` stays the same after delete/edit, it won't be triggered. I guess I can have an incremental flag, and let the `useEffect` monitor it as well. But it might not be the best practice? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 8):

All you need to do is to take the `fetchData` method out of `useEffect` and call it when you need it. Also make sure you pass the function as param in dependency array.

```
const useDataApi = (initialUrl, initialData) => {
  const [url, setUrl] = useState(initialUrl)

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(dataFetchReducer, { data: initialData, loading: true })

  const fetchData = useCallback(async () => {
      dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_INIT' })
      const result = await instance.get(url)
      dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_SUCCESS', payload: result.data })
  }, [url]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData()
  }, [url, fetchData]); // Pass fetchData as param to dependency array

  const doFetch = url => {
    setUrl(url)
  }

  return { ...state, doFetch, fetchData }
}
```

Comment: You return fetchData from custom hoook and call it on the custom action

Comment: Will not fetchData get a new value for each call to useDataApi so it will always trigger UseEffect?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, you need to also wrap fetchData with useCallback so that it is only created again when url changes

Comment: See also this blog post: https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/#but-i-cant-put-this-function-inside-an-effect

Comment: I guess when using useCallback() then useEffect() no longer need to list url in its deps since it implicitly depends on url through fetchData?